# ActiveRecord migration to add serialize to model with existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

I have an AR model whose corresponding table already has data (JSON strings, to be exact.)

I want to use the AR `serialize` helper (and YAML) instead of JSON and use my old data; is there a Ruby (not SQL) based solution other than the obvious one of:

1. Make a new column which is serialized
2. Copy the JSON string data from the old column to the new one after running through `JSON.parse`
3. Drop the old column and rename the new column (optionally).

Comment: What db are you using? hstore might be a good option for you - https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore

Comment: I don't mean that I want to know how to store the data, in the underlying DB's format. I meant, that if I add the `serialize` helper, then the attribute accessor no longer works, so `rec.attr = JSON.parse(rec.attr)` is not an option. Maybe I should say this explicitly in the question?